# Configuring convention for all members with type in automapper

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

All my domain models have field `public CurrencyId CurrencyId {get; set;}`. All my view models have filed `public CurrencyVm Currency {get; set;}`. Automapper knows how to `Map<CurrencyVm>(CurrencyId)`. How can I setup automatic convention, so I do not have to `.ForMember(n => n.Currency, opt => opt.MapFrom(n => n.CurrencyId));`?

Comment: You need ForAllMaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForAllMaps` is the answer, thanks @LucianBargaoanu. This code kinda works, but hasn't been tested in all cases. Also I do not know how to check if exists mapping between choosen properties.

```
        configuration.ForAllMaps((map, expression) =>
        {
            if (map.IsValid != null)
            {
                return; // type is already mapped (or not)
            }

            const string currencySuffix = "Id";
            var currencyPropertyNames = map.SourceType
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(n => n.PropertyType == typeof(CurrencyId) && n.Name.EndsWith(currencySuffix))
                .Select(n => n.Name.Substring(0, n.Name.Length - currencySuffix.Length))
                .ToArray();
            expression.ForAllOtherMembers(n =>
            {
                if (currencyPropertyNames.Contains(n.DestinationMember.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    n.MapFrom(n.DestinationMember.Name + currencySuffix);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is way too complicated. Try ForAllMaps with ForAllMembers and the string based MapFrom.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu but my problem is complex - I want to map CurrencyId to currency, but also SummaryCurrencyId to SummaryCurrency etc.

Comment: Yes, and in ForAllMembers you can check that for each member.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu in ForAllOtherMembers I do not have access to sourcemember, only destination, so I cannot compare names, and check if mapping is valid, etc.

Comment: You also don't have access to the source member your way. I still think ForAllMembers would be better.

Comment: I do - `currencyProperties = map.SourceType.GetProperties()` there is check if source member is `CurrencyId`, and if it ends with `Id`.

Comment: OK, and you can pass that into ForAllMembers, right? :)

Comment: Yes, but without the outer for each.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu edited answer to reflect this, but I kinda dislike this solution because of that id reconstruction and all that collections captured in lambdas. Also I dislike using automapper apis, because they like to mess it in new versions :/

Comment: I forgot about [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#recognizing-pre-postfixes).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I saw that, but it is not that good IMO. Generally I feel that automapper has tendency to create huge mess and unexpected errors, that's why I want my mapping to be precise. Automatically mapping StuffId to Stuff feels too overwhelming for me.